# Excel formula to reference multiple criteria in multiple columns

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a formula to return back a row number in excel.  Basically I have two different tables that I want to link.  In the employee section under the reference column, I want to place a formula that will reference a number if certain criteria is met.

For example,  I want to be able to take 2256 (numb for tom) and search the "assign" column in the building table for a match, then look if the cell directly next to it denotes if it is overtime or not (x is overtime), I then want it to return the reference number for the corresponding row in array B3:B7 for shifts that match the number of the employee but are not overtime.  If it fails to find something that matches those two criteria, I need it to return the number 0.  In this case I want tom to have a reference number reported of 1, liz it have a reference of 4, and kathy to show 3.  Amber should remain blank.

```
Building

Ref     Post     Start     End     assign     overtime   
 1       sh      1600      2400     2256               
 2       sn      600       1400     2057         x     
 3       sh      1000      1800     2107              
 4       sd      1400      2200     2057              
 5       dc      700       1500     2256         x


Employee

Name     Numb     Start    End     Post        Reference

tom      2256       day     eve      sh            ??

Liz      2057       day     eve      sd            ??

Amber    2952       day     eve      none          ??

kathy    2107       day     eve      sh            ??
```

Can someone please help with this formula?  I have tried versions of sumproduct, index, match, if, and and always getting an error.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using your sample data, the formula would be:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$6,MATCH(1,INDEX(($E$2:$E$6=B10)*($F$2:$F$6=""),),0)),"")
```

However, that only returns the Ref number of the first match.  Is there ever a time when there could be more than one occurrence? If so, what should the result be?

If it can only ever have a single occurrence, perhaps a simple `SUMIFS` would be better for you:

```
=SUMIFS($A$2:$A$6,$E$2:$E$6,B10,$F$2:$F$6,"")
```

And then format the sheet to not display 0s, or use a custom format to hide them: `0;0;;@`

Of course, as always, adjust ranges to suit

Answer (score 0):

No disrespect to the formula answer, I am sure it works well.
There are many solutions to your problem, mine is not necessarily the best.
However...
You might want to try to write a VB macro to accomplish the task.
In case you are unaware, macros are a simple type of programming, learning how to use macros opens a whole world of useful possibilities in excel. (If you have the time and inclination)
With a macro you can label the variables, check the results and debug easily, as well as modify it with any future enhancements.
You can run a macro using the Developer-> Visual Basic sub-menu.
Running and debugging a macro is easy and fun...try it and see

```
Public Sub Employee_Not_Overtime_Check()
'
    Dim iMaxEmployee As Long
    Dim iMaxBuilding As Long
    Dim irow As Long
    Dim iEmpNum As Long
    Dim iReference As Integer

'   Initialisation, stop screen refresh during macro execution

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    iMaxBuilding = Sheets("Building").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    iMaxEmployee = Sheets("Employee").UsedRange.Rows.Count

'    For debug, setting limits smaller



     iMaxBuilding = 10
       iMaxEmployee = 10


'   Loop through the Employee Records, for each one check their overtime status

        irow = 2
        Do While irow <= iMaxEmployee
            Sheets("Employee").Select
            iEmpNum = Cells(irow, 2).Value

            Call CheckOvertime(iEmpNum, iMaxBuilding, iReference)

            Sheets("Employee").Select
            Cells(irow, 6).Value = iReference

            irow = irow + 1
        Loop


        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True


    End Sub

Function CheckOvertime(ByVal iEmpNum As Long, ByVal iMaxBuilding As Long, ByRef iReference As Integer)

    Dim irow As Long

    Sheets("Building").Select

    iReference = 0

    For irow = 2 To iMaxBuilding
        If Cells(irow, 5).Value = iEmpNum Then
            If Cells(irow, 6).Value <> "x" Then
                 iReference = Cells(irow, 1).Value
                 Exit For
            End If
        End If

    Next irow

End Function
```